# Difference between two C code reading register

Tags: c

I would like to know the difference between these 2 codes. The first

```
int32_t lsm6dso32_temperature_raw_get(stmdev_ctx_t *ctx, int16_t *val)
  uint8_t buff[2];
  int32_t ret;
  ret = lsm6dso32_read_reg(ctx, LSM6DSO32_OUT_TEMP_L, buff, 2);
  val[0] = (int16_t)buff[1];
  val[0] = (val[0] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[0];
  return ret;
}
```

And this one

```
//some code here
uint8_t buffer[14];
data_reg.read(buffer, 14);

rawTemp = buffer[1] << 8 | buffer[0];
//some other code here
```

The first code comes from ST and the second comes from Adafruit, all these code are made for `LSM6DSO32` 6 dof captor. I'am only interested in reading byte. what is the difference between

```
val[0] = (int16_t)buff[1];
val[0] = (val[0] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[0];
```

And this

```
rawTemp = buffer[1] << 8 | buffer[0];
```

Is one solution better than the other ? All of these code read raw temperature from the captor.

Edit `rawTemp` is `int16_t`

Comment: Define "better". But the second one is very succinct and clear about what it's doing, whereas the first one is unnecessarily verbose about it. The casts in the first one are about the only thing that might seem to make a difference, but in fact they're not needed because the `char` operands go through normal integer promotions to `int` anyway, and that must be 16+ bits. Beyond that, you can use a pencil and paper to analyse what both variants do (the same thing).

Comment: The second one possibly invokes UB on small microcontroller systems. Correct code would be `(uint16_t)buffer[1] << 8`.

Comment: Actually the first one might integer overflow too. If compatibility with 8- or 16 bit MCUs is important, then don't use either version. If you are using a 32 bitter then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two methods may be identical in their defined behavior, depending on the type of `rawTemp`, which we are not shown. However, neither is a generally correct way to decode an `int16_t` value from two eight-bit bytes.

Considering this code first:

```
val[0] = (int16_t)buff[1];
val[0] = (val[0] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[0];
```

`buff[1]` is `uint8_t`, so its values range from to 255, so `val[0]*256` can range from 0 to 255•256 = 65,280. `val[0]` is `int16_t`, so its values range from −32,768 to +32,767. So this assignment may exceed what can be stored in `val[0]`. In that case, the result of the conversion is implementation-defined.

Further, the type of `val[0]*256` is `int` (due to the usual arithmetic conversions). So, if `int` is 16 bit, then `val[0]*256` may overflow what is representable in `int`, in which case the behavior is undefined.

Considering this code:

```
int16_t rawTemp;
rawTemp = buffer[1] << 8 | buffer[0];
```

`buffer[1] << 8` may also overflow `int`. Since the behavior is undefined, an overflow is not required to produce the same result as the above code, particularly since the operation is different (shift versus multiplication) and it is combined with the other byte in a different way (bitwise OR instead of addition).

As with the first code, an implementation-defined conversion may occur in the assignment. If so, and the right side of the assignment does not overflow (perhaps because `int` is 32 bits), then the conversion will produce the same result as in the first code, since it is implementation-defined.

In the absence of assurance that the first byte is less than 128 or that `int` is more than 16 bits and the implementation-defined conversion wraps modulo 2<sup>16</sup>, neither of these is a correct way to decode an `int16_t` from two eight-bit bytes.

C is deficient in good ways to reassemble a signed integer from bits. The various arithmetic and bit operators get hung up on the sign bit and overflows. One method is to assemble an unsigned integer and copy its bits into a signed integer:

```
uint16_t t = (uint16_t) buffer[1] << 8 | buffer[0];
int16_t ret;
memcpy(&ret, &t, sizeof ret);
```

A good compiler will generate code that eliminates the `memcpy`.

(Note all of the above assumes a little-endian representation—the earlier byte, `buffer[0]` goes into the low bits (“little end”) of the value.)

Comment: `rawTemp` is defined by `int16_t` @Eric Postpischil

Comment: @simon: Edit that into the question.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, so what is the best way to decode an two eight-bit bytes ?

Comment: @simon In this case, you need to read what endianess the accelerometer uses before anything else. Both examples seem to assume little endian, but looking at the datasheet, it apparently supports both little and big. Preferably pick the same one as your MCU is using.

Comment: @Lundin I use an `SAMD21` comes from Atmel

Comment: @simon 32 bit Little endian then. So you don't need to worry about using the sloppy code from ST or Ada, it will work in your case.

Comment: @simon: I added discussion of a correct method in the answer.